# MaxConcurrentCalls, how do I tell the client that its call has been queued? BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, client, client-server

I have a WCF service with a long running method (doing all kinds of biology related lookups and alignments and weird stuff).

The code utilizes the RAM and cpus well for a single method call, so allowing too many concurrent calls just bogs it down on memory. So really I wouldn't mind setting MaxConcurrentCalls to 1. (I currently have it at 3 which is OK).

My concern is that when the method is called and queued, I would like my client to immediately know it got queued. Is that possible?

Or just not have it queue at all and respond with some fault, is that possible?

At the very least I would like if the client disconnects or times out I'd like it to NOT process, is that possible?
 (I think if it times out it may in fact not process, but if I give it like 6 requests at the same time, then close all the clients it seems like it runs -eventually- all 6 requests. I shortened the timeout and I think it may have NOT run all 6, I'll have to investigate more)

I just don't want the client spinning for 3 minutes (our timeout - which only is ever hit if things are queued), then after the 3 minutes handling the timeout. I would rather it just recognize the queue is full and say try back later immediately, or maybe we could increase our timeout (but then I would want to immediately say 'hey, you're queued it might be awhile'). I definitely don't want it timing out so the client waits and gets nothing AND it still processes on the backend.

I saw some stuff on a setting for net.tcp listenBacklog setting, but we're using a different binding, would we have to switch? Would switching work?

Comment: Why not have the service method check to see if the "queue" is full, and it is return a SOAP fault to that effect?

Comment: I would love to exactly this, but I don't see anywhere how/if it is possible to check the queue. WCF handles the queue when you set the MaxConcurrentCalls, it starts outing calls over the max into a queue. But I don't seem to have control of it.

Comment: You can't send any information before the call is processed. You need to implement own methods like id enqueue() getstatus(id) instead of calling longmethod() immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concurrent way to tell the user the queue is full, Microsoft is limiting the access to queuing from the code for obvious reasons, Microsoft does not want you to start messing around with the queue, unless it's for controlling it for programming purposes, for example, moving the call up the queue or giving importance for one call to the queue over another.

If you want the check when the queue is full, there are couple of ways to do this:

Use, `await, lock, mutex` calls when the queue is full and prompt a message to the client, this is not the most comfortable way but it's useful as it will require you use multi threading.

Connect your WCF to the Microsoft's MSMQ service and query the messaging queue itself. It is very useful but a burden, as many call to the MSMQ will need to be issued for every user.

There is not straight forward way to tell the user he is queued unfortunately, As I encountered this problem myself many times and had to do workarounds.

In my case, mutex was my workaround savior, nowadays I would suggest using await calls rather on querying the MSMQ, it might require to open another thread, but it will provide you with what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Accept more calls (maxconcurrentcalls = 10). In your method do count of current parallel calls (InterlockedIncrement at the beginning, InterlockedDecrement in finally block) in case if the InterlockedIncrement Returned bigger than 3 (your max count of parallel processing) terminate the current processing (throw exception).

To sum up: accept many calls, terminate earlier those which would be too much for server to handle.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was, to implement a Service.IsServiceAvailable Method, which returns true.

From the client I first call this Method with a short Time-Out Behavior. When I get no Exception with this ping, I call the Worker-Method.

I think, this works good enough in my scenario with named pipe on one Machine, when the Client-Instances are generated through User-Interaction.

But thinking about it, I'd prefer @Mikl X Answer.